# Ajax function can't be called on the second page, AJAX, PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a working ajax function with 7 parameter, but the parameter that I'll be mainly focusing on today is the fifth parameter called "stop". When the fifth parameter "stop", is set to "true", the current ajax function stops the setTimeout, and basically doesn't call itself ever again, unless it's triggered again from outside sources. It works, but here's the problem:

Instead of setting the stop variable to "true" from inside the ajax function, and passing it to the recursive setTimeout ajax function inside the main ajax function, in order to stop the ajax function from calling itself again, I need to check some data in my database in **test6.php**, and if it's true, then I would call the function timeoutAjax(), and pass in "true" for the fifth parameter to stop the ajax function from calling itself again.

But I can't seem to do that for some reason. Calling the function timeoutAjax() in test6.php, and passing in "true" for the fifth parameter just doesn't work, even though passing in "true" for the fifth paremeter on **test5.php**  *would*  work. Not sure what I did wrong. Please take a look at my code:

**test5.php**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type = "text/javascript">

var queues = {};
function timeoutAjax(url, theName, id, timeout, stop, addBy, rewindAt) {

var input = document.getElementById(theName).value; // or $('#t').val();

if (stop == "true") {
stop = true;
}

    clearInterval(queues[theName]);
    // make the call
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: { input : input, timeout : timeout },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(error);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = data;
            // queue a new call
        if (stop != true) {
            queues[theName] = setInterval(function () {
                timeout+=addBy;
                if (timeout >= (rewindAt+addBy)) {
                timeout = addBy;
                }    
                timeoutAjax(url, theName, id, timeout, stop, addBy, rewindAt);            
            }, timeout);
        }
        },
        complete: function(){
            $('input[name="'+theName+'"]').prop("disabled",false);
        },
        beforeSend: function(){
            $('input[name="'+theName+'"]').prop("disabled",true);
        }
    });
}
</script>

<textarea id = 't' rows = "25" cols = "50" onKeyDown="if(event.keyCode==13) timeoutAjax('test6.php','t','output',3000,'false',3000,15000)"> </textarea>
<div id = 'output'> </div>
```

**test6.php**

```
<?php

$input = nl2br($_POST['input']);

echo $input

//checks something in database. 
//if true, set the fifth parameter in the ajax function to true

echo "<script>
timeoutAjax('test6.php','t','output',3000,'true',3000,15000);
</script>";

?>
```

Comment: I don't understand the relationship between these two scripts.  Does the ajax call in test5.php call test6.php?  Why are you outputting javascript from test6.php?  Why does that ajax call in test6.php call itself?  Honestly, this looks like a convoluted mess.

Comment: No. The ajax script itself is in test5.php, it calls the function, which lead it to test6.php. I need to check something in my database on test6.php, and if it returns true, I need to pass in "true", to the fifth parameter in the function, so the function can stop calling itself recursively, but I'm not sure if I can do that on the second page, and that's why I'm asking.

Comment: @MikeBrant Just tagging you to make sure you see this.

Comment: But why are you echoing javascript in test6.php? I think you need to take a step back and explain what functionality you are trying to achieve, and get some guidance on how to achieve that.  What you are showing now seems really poorly structured. For example, why would you need to make recursive calls to the same endpoint?

Comment: I need to pass a variable to the fifth parameter of the ajax function in test6.php. Is that possible, or can I only pass a variable to the ajax function in test5.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like **test6.php** *always* outputs a call to `timeoutAjax`, right? Sure, sometimes it passes a `stop` parameter that evaluates to `true`, but before you do anything with that variable to actually stop anything, you initiate another AJAX call to **test6.php**, which as we know, *always* calls `timeoutAjax`, which puts you into a loop. Is that the problem?

Perhaps you just need to move your `document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = data;` line inside your `if (stop != true)` check, so you don't re-call `timeoutAjax` with the response from **test6.php** if your `stop` parameter was true. But if you did this, you would still do your AJAX call one more time after you pass your `stop` parameter.

So maybe you just need to move your `stop` check outside of your AJAX call:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

var queues = {};
  function timeoutAjax(url, theName, id, timeout, stop, addBy, rewindAt) {

    var input = document.getElementById(theName).value; // or $('#t').val();

    if (stop == "true") {
        return; // just return here so you don't make the ajax call again.
    }

    clearInterval(queues[theName]);
    // make the call
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: { input : input, timeout : timeout },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(error);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = data;
            // queue a new call
            queues[theName] = setInterval(function () {
                timeout+=addBy;
                if (timeout >= (rewindAt+addBy)) {
                timeout = addBy;
                }    
                timeoutAjax(url, theName, id, timeout, stop, addBy, rewindAt);            
            }, timeout);
        },
        complete: function(){
            $('input[name="'+theName+'"]').prop("disabled",false);
        },
        beforeSend: function(){
            $('input[name="'+theName+'"]').prop("disabled",true);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Actually, it looks like you're also setting an interval to keep calling timeoutAjax on a regular basis. So not only are you calling it via your **test6.php** output, you're also calling it on an interval. Was that your intended behavior? Perhaps you don't need a `setInterval` at all. Perhaps not even a `stop` parameter. Just have **test6.php** output the script tag as you do now if it should be called again and do not output the script tag if it should not.

Comment: Yep. I actually do need the setInterval.

Comment: It was calling the ajax function on test6.php that was the problem. Couldn't pass in stop for the fifth parameter.

Comment: I could only call the function on test5.php, and not on test6.php, and that was the problem. Not where i put the if stop != true, because it works from test5.php when I called it with the parameter true.